# Assert which returns bool?

Tags: nunit

Does NUnit have an Assert method that returns a bool? They all return void. I am using version 2.5.3

Thanks

Comment: I imagine they either throw an exception, or the assertion passed. Why do you want a bool?

Answer (score 2):

All members of the Assert class are voids. For each void, if the assertion is incorrect an NUnit.Framework.AssertionException is thrown.

I suppose you could write your own wrappers around these voids that returned true if no exception was thrown and caught any exception and returned false, but I'm not sure what functionality this would give you.

Can you explain what you are trying to achieve that requires an assertion to return a bool?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I came along here over a decade later, looking for an answer to this exact question.

I'm writing a class to add to my test helpers that would perform a 'deep' equals, into nested objects, and arrays after being deserialized. I wanted to utilize Nunit's *Assert.Equals()*. Comparing values contained in different number value types is much harder than it first sounds. Integers, both signed and unsigned, of different bit sizes, decimals, floats, doubles, byte, sbyte, and even the odd stuff like IntPtr... *Assert.Equals()* holds up well with all of these, even if the types in question are incompatible with each other.

I was already legitimately using Nunit as my testing framework, so I wanted to avoid introducing a different equals comparison method that would potentially have different behavior than the one that other unit tests were already utilizing.

However, I didn't want this Assert to throw. I want to catalog all differences throughout the deep equals, and I may decide to throw afterwards, but that's irrelevant to the question at hand.

Sure, I could easily wrap a try/catch around every relevant occurrence of *Assert.Equals()*, or replace them with to calls to a single wrapped method; but I like to use to my debugger to walk through my process, and the less throws and redirects I introduce the easier it is to follow.

By it's very nature, a deep equals method is recursive, so there already is some bouncing around, and I don't want to add more.

TLDR: **I wanted a more elegant solution.**

I normally use their *Assert.Equals(expected, actual)* pattern, but a lot of developers I've worked with prefer to use the alternative *Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected))* pattern, because it reads more like a sentence.

After a little investigation with a decompilier, I found is that you can use the  *Is.EqualTo()* constraint independently of *Assert.That()*, avoiding  exceptions entirely:

```
Is.EqualTo(expected).ApplyTo(actual).IsSuccess
```

Full disclosure, I'm doing this in .Net 4.8, which is pretty much obsolete at the time of this writing, but this also should work on .net5, core, standard, mono and wherever else Nunit has been ported to.